# Rcpp Armadillo, submatrices and subvectors

Tags: rcpp, armadillo, submatrix

I try to translate some R code into [RcppArmadillo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/index.html) and therefore I would also like to do the following:

Assume there is a nonnegative vector `v` and a matrix `M`, both with for example `m` rows. I would like to get rid of all rows in the matrix `M` whenever there is a zero in the corresponding row of the vector `v` and afterwards also get rid of all entries that are zero in the vector `v`. Using R this is simply just the following:

```
M = M[v>0,]

v = v[v>0]
```

So my question is if there is a way to do this in RcppArmadillo. Since I am quite new to any programming language I was not able to find anything that could solve my problem, although I think that I am not the first one who asks this maybe quite easy question.

Answer (score 5):

Of course there is a way to go about subsetting elements in both Rcpp ([subsetting with Rcpp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/)) and RcppArmadillo ([Armadillo subsetting](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/)).

Here is a way to replicate the behavior of R subsets in Armadillo.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// Isolate by Row
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat vec_subset_mat(const arma::mat& x, const arma::uvec& idx) {
  return x.rows(find(idx > 0));
}

// Isolate by Element
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec subset_vec(const arma::vec& x) {
  return x.elem(find(x > 0));
}

/*** R
set.seed(1334)
m = matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
v = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T)

all.equal(m[v>0,], vec_subset_mat(m,v))
all.equal(v[v>0], as.numeric(subset_vec(v)))
*/
```

Comment: I am grateful to @coatless for tirelessly answering this here but it really is a duplicate question as I too have referenced the Rcpp Gallery on this a few times ...